# How to let touches go through a UIView that has a mask set

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, mask, quartz-core

I have a custom view that is shown at the bottom of the screen on iPhone with a mask set that makes the background transparent from the blue color you see in the screenshot. You can see that the "Sign In" button is behind this view with a transparent mask so when I try to tap the "Sign in" button the event does not go through. Is there a way to pass the event to the button when user taps on the transparent mask applied to this view?

[image]

Comment: Does it need to be specific to the masked area or can the whole view just be transparent to taps?

Comment: is it possible to move the button to the front? Or a second way is set user interaction of the transparent view to be disabled.

Comment: The button has to be behind. Tapping only on the transparent should go back to the views below.

Comment: Have you tried hitTest:withEvent: so you can pass touch event to the button behind?